# How to exclude a word using Regex for MobaXterm Syntax Highlighting?

Tags: regex, mobaxterm

I created a regex expression to match any string surrounded by quotation marks in a log such as "example" but exclude the word heartbeat if found.

```
[^0-9A-Za-z_&-]("(?!heartbeat)[A-Za-z0-9_.&?=%~#{}()@+-:]*")[^A-Za-z0-9_-]
```

I verified the expression in [regex101](https://regex101.com/) but once in MobaXterm it does not work. My assumption is MobaXterm does not handle Negative Lookaheads.

Keep in mind the following does work:

```
[^0-9A-Za-z_&-]("[A-Za-z0-9_.&?=%~#{}()@+-:]*")[^A-Za-z0-9_-]
```

Is there an alternative to what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: I believe this is not possible to do without negative lookahead assertion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make some hard to read regexes such as:

`"(?:[^h].*|h[^e].*|he[^a].*|hea[^r].*|etc...)"`

(replace `.*` with the second character class) but another option would be to write `"heartbeat"|([A-Za-z0-9_.&?=%~#{}()@+-:]*)`. When the string is `"heartbeat"` this will skip the capture group but that only works if your program is specifically looking for the capture group.

You can also place `\w` and `\d` in your character classes to make them simpler: `[^\d\w&-](?:"heartbeat"|("[\w\d.&?=%~#{}()@+-:]*"))[^\d\w-]`